# DAX equation to average data with different timespans

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have data for different companies. The data stops at day 10 for one of the companies (Company 1), day 6 for the others. If Company 1 is selected with other companies, I want to show the average so that the data runs until day 10, but using day 7, 8, 9, 10 values for Company 1 and day 6 values for others.

I'd want to just fill down days 8-10 for other companies with the day 6 value, but that would look misleading on the graph. So I need a DAX equation with some magic in it.

As an example, I have companies:

Company 1
Company 2
Company 3

etc. as a filter

And a table like:

| Company | Date | Day of Month | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Company 1 | 1.11.2022 | 1 | 10 |
| Company 1 | 2.11.2022 | 2 | 20 |
| Company 1 | 3.11.2022 | 3 | 21 |
| Company 1 | 4.11.2022 | 4 | 30 |
| Company 1 | 5.11.2022 | 5 | 40 |
| Company 1 | 6.11.2022 | 6 | 50 |
| Company 1 | 7.11.2022 | 7 | 55 |
| Company 1 | 8.11.2022 | 8 | 60 |
| Company 1 | 9.11.2022 | 9 | 62 |
| Company 1 | 10.11.2022 | 10 | 70 |
| Company 1 | 11.11.2022 | 11 | NULL |
| Company 2 | 1.11.2022 | 1 | 15 |
| Company 2 | 2.11.2022 | 2 | 25 |
| Company 2 | 3.11.2022 | 3 | 30 |
| Company 2 | 4.11.2022 | 4 | 34 |
| Company 2 | 5.11.2022 | 5 | 45 |
| Company 2 | 6.11.2022 | 6 | 100 |
| Company 2 | 7.11.2022 | 7 | NULL |

Every date has a row, but for days over 6/10 the count is NULL. If Company 1 or Company 2 is chosen separately, I'd like to show the count as is. If they are chosen together, I'd like the average of the two so that:

Day 5: AVG(40,45)
Day 6: AVG(50,100)
Day 7: AVG(55,100)
Day 8: AVG(60,100)
Day 9: AVG(62,100)
Day 10: AVG(70,100)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this?
Create a Matriz using your:
company_table_dim (M)
calendar_Days_Table(N)
So you will have a new table of MXN Rows

Go to PowerQuery Order DATA and FillDown your QTY column
(= Table.FillDown(#"Se expandió Fact_Table",{"QTY"}))

So your last known QTY will de filled til the end of Time_Table for any company filters

Cons: Consider your new Matriz MXN it could be millions of rows to calculate
Greetings

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERPSQ.jpg)

Comment: I don't want to fill down, because 6th and 10th day are deadlines. It would look like going over the deadline, yet accomplishing nothing after it. Unless there's some way to dynamically hide part of the data?